# Python list and class

Tags: python, list

```
class Event:
    def __init__(self, event_date, event_type, machine_name, user):
        self.date = event_date
        self.type = event_type
        self.machine = machine_name
        self.user = user
events = [
 Event('2020-01-21 12:45:56', 'login', 'myworkstation.local', 'jordan'),
 Event('2020-01-22 15:53:42', 'logout', 'webserver.local', 'jordan'),
 Event('2020-01-21 18:53:21', 'login', 'webserver.local', 'lane'),
 Event('2020-01-22 10:25:34', 'logout', 'myworkstation.local','jordan'),
 Event('2020-01-21 08:20:01', 'login', 'webserver.local', 'jordan'),
 Event('2020-01-23 11:24:35', 'logout', 'mailserver.local', 'chris'),]
```

As the above list contains the elements as a class, I am confused about the naming of the class. I am a beginner, learning python. Whenever I created a class there was always a name for it, like student1 for a Student Class.
Kindly someone explain.

Comment: Access the objects with `events[0], events[1], etc` And the members with `events[0].date, events[3].machine, etc`.

Comment: It's the same as a list of `int`, you don't have a name for each `int` in `[1, 2, 3]`. You just access them with indices. Same here - `events[0]` etc.

Comment: a list contains elements. in your case, those elements are references to objects. even if you had created the object with some name ```obj1 = Event(data...)``` and then added that event to a list ```temp_list.append(obj1)```, if you were to print that list, it would display the str output that the class is configured to print when outputted to stdout. variable names aren't inherently part of the variable, they're just used for the interpreter to be able to differentiate what data your referencing. if you want to name events, add an attribute and constructor arg so each event has a .name

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
event0 = Event('2020-01-21 12:45:56', 'login', 'myworkstation.local', 'jordan')
event1 = Event('2020-01-22 15:53:42', 'logout', 'webserver.local', 'jordan')
...
```

Here, you would have `n` references to `Event` objects, stored in `n` different variables `event0`, `event1`, etc.

When you define your list, you still have `n` references to `Even` objects; they are just stored in a *list* instead of in distinct variables. You refer to them *through* the list, as `events[0]`, `events[1]`, etc.